# Can radio waves with multiple frequencies have the same power?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, frequency, power, radio-frequency

I was watching data from a spectrum analyzer that shows the frequency of the wave and its power in dBm. I noticed that all frequencies were operating at the same power; however, I don't understand how this is possible. Any explanation is appreciated for why this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because your transmitted signal has uniform power density distribution. The oldest example and best-known is the FM radio signal: $x(t)=A_0cos\left(\omega_ct +\int m(t)\right)dt$ where $m(t)$ is the information carrying signal and $\omega_c$ is the carrier frequency. If $|m(t)|<<\omega_c$ then the power density is essentially flat. You can think of it having an oscillator and you slowly change the frequency of an oscillation at a rate $m(t)$ by changing its resonant frequency, say a value of capacitor, hence the name VCO (Voltage Controlled Oscillator).